# function is returning value ,result is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hi I have tried this function .This function will give be row number till 'b' exist in same column

```
var arr= ['abc','tbu','iop'];

var getPositionbyRow = function(row, col) {
if(arr[row][col]!=='b') {
        return row;
    }

    getPositionbyRow(row+1,col);
}
var  r = getPositionbyRow(0,1);
```

but value of r is always undefined. can someone help me to understand why its happening. Thanks for help.

Comment: **Please** do not update question based on suggestions in answer/comments. This makes them void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your recursive function to work you should `return getPositionbyRow(row+1,col);`

Also it is a good practise to add a condition when 'b' is not present in your array, and return -1 for example. That way you will avoid endless loops

Comment: Thanks realized mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You only return something if `arr[row][col]!=='b'`. Otherwise you return nothing.

You need to

```
return getPositionbyRow(row+1,col);
```

Comment: Thanks realized mistake.